# RewriteMap inside RewriteCond doesn't work (Apache)

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewritecond, rewritemap

I have a `RewriteCond` that checks if `{QUERY_STRING}` contains the right version number, if it doesn't then redirect users to the correct version.

For instance if v0.7 is the latest, users accessing `http://localhost/?v=0.5` should be redirected to `http://localhost/?v=0.7` but for some reason, if am using `RewriteMap` in the conditions, it doesn't work...

This works

```
RewriteMap versions txt:/var/www/html/version.txt
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" !^v=0.7
RewriteRule "^/$" "/?v=${versions:version}" [R,L]
```

**This doesn't**

```
RewriteMap versions txt:/var/www/html/version.txt
RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" !^v=${versions:version}
RewriteRule "^/$" "/?v=${versions:version}" [R,L]
```

Content of version.txt

```
##
##  version.txt -- rewriting map
##  The version number written here will be mapped to the URL
##
##
version 0.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond "%{QUERY_STRING}" !^v=${versions:version}
> ```

This doesn't work because the *CondPattern* (2nd argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) is a regex and consequently does not support variable expansion. (Just as you can't use backreferences of the form `$n` or `%n` or server variables `%(SERVER_VAR}` or env vars `%{ENV:MY_ENV_VAR}` etc.) It would otherwise conflict with the PCRE regex syntax. Only the *TestString* (first argument to the `RewriteCond` directive) and the `RewriteRule` *substitution* arguments support variable expansion, since these arguments are "regular" strings, not regex.

However, you can still do what you require and check that the correct version number, as returned from the `RewriteMap`, is present at the start of the query string. Instead, expand the result of the `RewriteMap` in the *TestString* (which does support variable expansion since this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex) and *compare* this using an internal backreference.

For example, change the `RewriteCond` to read:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}@${versions:version} !^v=([\d.]+)(?:&[^@]*)?@\1
```

After the variable expansion, we end up matching a string of the form `v=0.5@0.7` against the regex `^v=([\d.]+)(?:&.*)?@\1`. `\1` is an internal backreference to the first captured subpattern (ie. the value of the `v` URL parameter).  So, this effectively matches the URL parameter value against the value returned from the `RewriteMap`. This whole expression is then *negated* (`!` prefix) so it's successful when the condition does *not* match, ie. the version number is different.

`([\d.]+)` - Matches the version number in the query string, which consists of 1 or more digits or literal dots. eg. `0.5`

`(?:&.*)?` - Matches the remainder of the query string (if any).

`@` is just an arbitrary string that does not otherwise occur in the query string or "version" string.

You don't need to surround the arguments in double-quotes unless they contain *spaces* (even then you can backslash escape the spaces instead). So, the double quotes are entirely optional in this example. The same applies to the `RewriteRule` directive.

Comment: The perfect answer! Really appreciate the detailed explanation and also the provided solution works perfectly. Thank you @MrWhite!